# MessageConversionException occurred when mapping string date to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, localdatetime

I have a queue that listens to a topic and my listener receives a DTO.
I need to parse the String to `LocalDateTime` but I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Text '2020-06-18 11:12:46' could not be parsed at index 10
```

Here is the message details

```
{"id":444, "details":{"TYPE":[1]},"dateOccurred":"2020-06-18 11:12:46"}"]
```

And here is how I set it in my DTO

```
public class PlanSubscriptionDto {
    private Long id;

    private Map<String, List<Long>> details;

    private LocalDateTime dateOccurred;

    public void setDateOccurred(String dateTime) {
        this.dateOccurred = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
//ive also tried this
//this.dateOccurred = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG));
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!
Any advice would we great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a format pattern string to define the format.

```
public class PlanSubscriptionDto {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    private Long id;

    private Map<String, List<Long>> details;

    private LocalDateTime dateOccurred;

    public void setDateOccurred(String dateTime) {
        this.dateOccurred = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, FORMATTER);
    }
}
```

### Why didn’t your code work?

ISO 8601 format has a `T` between the date and the time. There’s no `T` in your date-time string, so `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` cannot parse it.

### Variants

Now we’re at it, I’d like to show a couple of other options. Taste differs, so I can’t tell which one you’ll like the best.

You may put in the `T` to obtain ISO 8601 format. Then you will need no explicit formatter. The one-arg `LocalDateTime.parse()` parses ISO 8601 format.

```
    public void setDateOccurred(String dateTime) {
        dateTime = dateTime.replace(' ', 'T');
        this.dateOccurred = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime);
    }
```

Or sticking to the formatter and the space between date and time, we can define the formatter in this wordier way:

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();
```

What we get for the extra code lines is (1) more reuse of built-in formatters (2) this formatter will accept time without seconds and time with a fraction of second too because `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` does.

### Link

[Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thank you so much! -_- At first I thought there was something wrong with my mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned that this is also an option for the parsing :)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime dateOccurred;
```